# Task Schedule on resume from idle?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

With schtasks.exe (Windows Task Scheduler for command prompt), you can make a task that is triggered on idle, which I use. However, is it possible to make a trigger on resume from idle? I.E., when the computer is no longer idle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no trigger on idle end, but there is one for idle start.
Here is an idea how to use it for solving the problem :

- Create a scheduled dummy task for which :

  - Start condition is On idle
  - Stop condition is if the computer ceases to be idle
- Create another task that waits for the dummy task to start,
  and triggers the wanted action when it stops.

Use whatever tools fit the job, such as perhaps [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Ok I can probably use a simple bat file using task list. Thank you!

Comment: How can you make a task wait for another task? I cannot find any setting in Task Scheduler that allows this.

Comment: @LPChip: The Task Scheduler is not well-adapted for it. The second task could be started by the first one, and wait upon some object. I can think of a dummy window started by the first task with a known title, which AutoHotkey can track. Or perhaps a file created/deleted when the first task finishes, where the second task loops on checking its existence (which does not require AutoHotkey).

Comment: Right... so its not an option in TaskScheduler itself... That's why I couldn't find it. If programming is going to be the way anyway, I'll either stick to the workstation lock/unlock (both supported by task scheduler, or program something in Visual Studio Core, which will give me far more control anyway, such as: if inactive for 5 minutes... if inactive for 15 minutes... when active... if cpu usage is below... etc...